# Polygons and MultiPolygons should follow the right-hand rule

Tags: geojson

http://geojsonlint.com/ I get error

```
 Polygons and MultiPolygons should follow the right-hand rule
```

I used it for past 3 years without any problem with my old GeoJSON file.
Now geojsonlint enforce the right hand rule, how to fix the problem.

---

### Updated in July 2022

**So what is right hand rule for polygon in GeoJSON format?**

[polygon definition, click here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-3.1.6)

[image]

### A good example of create 4 point rectangle viewport bbox bounding box use GeoJSON

[image]

Comment: Hi OP, can you mark an answer as accepted pls?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of August 2016 GeoJSON is now [a formal IETF specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946).  And some things have changed from the [old informal 2008 spec](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec).  So to be valid for the 2016 spec your polygons **MUST** be right-hand wound.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.6

The use of **MUST** indicates an absolute requirement of the specification.
However then the subsequent language about not rejecting other windings is weird and is open to some argument - perhaps parsers should accept and correct other windings.  I think this what lead geojsonlint (from geojsonhint) to use the word **should** instead of **MUST** in their feedback message.

So I agree with the [position of geojsonlint.com](https://github.com/JasonSanford/geojsonlint.com/issues/26) as they place right at the top of their page the link to the 2016 spec.  Your polygons are bad per the 2016 spec. But yet they are fine per the informal 2008 spec.  So if you do not wish to change the winding of your polygons, you will need to make certain any linters or parsers you use honor the old 2008 spec and do not one day suddenly migrate to the new formal spec.

Or perhaps you should consider changing your polygon winding as doing so will get you in line with both specs and better positioned for the future as the 2008 spec fades away.

Note that for me the largest change in the 2016 spec was the dropping utterly of the support for coordinate systems.  I had all my GeoJSON in NAD83 and then had to quietly remove that as now all GeoJSON is WGS84.  Fortunately for me coming from Oracle Spatial all my polygons were already right-hand wound.

Comment: For me it would be good if geojsonlint had on option to skip the winding test, or report that as a separate issue. That is what the specification is somehow recommending as well.

Comment: My polygons were generated by postgis `ST_AsGeoJSON` function and are bad too.

Comment: I had the problem @MagnoC described. This answer helped me https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306567/postgis-geojson-query-not-validating  In short, wrap the value passed to ST_AsGeoJSON in ST_ForcePolygonCCW

Answer (score 17):

The [Right Hand Rule GeoJSON Fixer | Mapster](https://mapster.me/right-hand-rule-geojson-fixer/) page has a client-side JavaScript function that fixes the right hand rule problem.

Comment: This service isn't working anymore, in FF or Chrome

Comment: @Henrik : I've just used it working correctly in FF.70. Maybe it's back.

Comment: Hi it is working correctly, if you would like to do it yourself you can checkout https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-rewind / https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mapbox/geojson-rewind

Answer (score 11):

For anyone finding this and looking for a tool to fix them. GDALs ogr2ogr can take "2008" spec GeoJSON and write out in "RFC7946" standard mode (with polygons following the right-hand rule for orientation).

`ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -lco RFC7946=YES output.json input.json`

or for use in scripts where you want to input and output the GeoJSON as a string:

`echo 'Your GeoJSON' | ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -lco RFC7946=YES /vsistdout/ /vsistdin/`

Answer (score 9):

[Click here for what is right hand rule](https://dev.to/jinagamvasubabu/solution-polygons-and-multipolygons-should-follow-the-right-hand-rule-2c8i#:%7E:text=A%20linear%20ring%20MUST%20follow,counterclockwise%2C%20and%20holes%20are%20clockwise.)

My old GeoJSON worked with Google Maps, Leaflet, OpenLayers, Mapbox, Bing Maps, etc.
however failed [geojsonlint.com](http://geojsonlint.com) validate.

I have to use another website to validate:
http://geojson.io

Answer (score 6):

This can be fixed very easily in Python using [`geojson-rewind`](https://pypi.org/project/geojson-rewind/).

```
from geojson_rewind import rewind

rewoundGeoJSON = rewind(geoJSONString)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit late to the party, but `geojsonlint` uses a buggy version of geojsonhint` (the underlying validator).

`geojsonhint` attempts to validate ring orientations by calculating negative / positive area, but does so incorrectly.

In other words, the validation error from the site cannot be trusted at this point in time.