# PostGIS GeoJson Query Not Validating

Tags: postgis, geojson

I am using  the following query to create a GeoJson response:

```
SELECT json_build_object(
    'type',         'FeatureCollection',
    'features',     jsonb_agg(feature)
)
FROM (
    SELECT json_build_object(
        'type',         'Feature',
        'id',           id,
        'geometry',     ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_ForcePolygonCW(wkb_geometry))::json,
        'properties',   to_jsonb(row) - 'id' - 'wkb_geometry'
    ) AS feature
    FROM (SELECT * FROM gis_states LIMIT 1) AS row
) AS features
```

The resulting data-set (https://pastebin.com/hvFQXUTr) does not validate at http://geojsonlint.com, even though I am using `ST_ForcePolygonCW`:

> Line 1: Polygons and MultiPolygons should follow the right-hand rule

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259944/polygons-and-multipolygons-should-follow-the-right-hand-rule

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, so the documentation (https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ForceRHR.html) states that `ST_ForcePolygonCW` is a synonym of `ST_ForceRHR()`. However, I wonder if the linter at http://geojsonlint.com/ is working properly, or perhaps the error is too ambiguous, as I got it to render correctly by using `ST_ForcePolygonCCW`, which is the opposite.

Comment: The problem is that "Right-Hand-Rule" isn't a very useful term in GIS. Some GIS software (e.g., PostGIS) uses it to refer mean that the interior of a boundary is to your right as you walk around it (clockwise orientation). In most other contexts, it refers to the direction your fingers curl when the thumb of your right hand is pointing towards your head (counterclockwise orientation).

Comment: This answer was very helpful, thanks. Multiple linters confirm `ST_ForcePolygonCCW` produces valid output for GeoJSON